# What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?

Tags: colloquial-language, spoken-language

> 完成前とずいぶん色が違うじゃねぇか！

In this sentence, what is じゃねぇか?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

じゃねぇか is just a colloquial form of the tag question じゃないか.

Comment: So じゃ　here is not the colloquial of では　as it usually is?

Comment: Yes it is!
じゃねえか comes from じゃないか, which is the colloquial contraction of　ではないか？ (in English they would be very similar to: ain't it, isn't it and is it not, respectively)

Comment: What is derogatory about it?  It is plain Kanto  colloquial.

Comment: Umm, are you still here? If you have time can you explain me why と　particle is being used? "Before completion AND the color not extremely differ!" I must be doing this wrong somewhere. (It's a step-by-step artwork article. This is the 5th step, 05 : 完成)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, hopefully 非回答者 can help you better! Meanwhile, I believe it means "The color is really different compared to before completion, isn't it?" where 完成前と is short for 完成前と比べて (compared to before completion...) For sure, と has a few other uses than "with" (read this! http://japanese.about.com/library/weekly/aa121601a.htm)

Answer (score 15):

This doesn't only happen with じゃない > じゃねえ, but generally /ai/ > /ee/, like

> きたない > きたねえ
>   やばい > やべえ
>   (食{た}べたい = ) 食{く}いたい > 食いてえ

As in the other answer, this is extremely informal and in the wrong context can easily be considered plain rude.

<sub>Xと違う = to differ from X

完成前 = before completion</sub>

**Edit.**
For completeness, there's also

- /ae/ > /ee/
  e.g. お前 > おめえ
- /oi/ > /ee/
  e.g. すごい > すげえ
- /ui/ > /ii/
  e.g. さむい > さみい, まずい > まじい