# Meaning of わりィ in this sentence

Tags: meaning, contractions, reading-comprehension

> **わりィ**のはその関口って奴じゃねぇか。

I'm guessing that this って is という rather than は. So I get something like

> It's that idiot Sekiguchi isn't it?

I can't even begin to guess at what the わりィ part is though.

Comment: This answer might be of some help... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/9831 /ui/ ⇒ /ii/  Eg. さむい⇒さみぃ、あつい⇒あちぃ、まずい⇒まじぃ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a phonetic reduction of 悪い{わるい}.

So we can translate the sentence as

> わりィのはその関口って奴じゃねぇか。

*The one who's in the wrong is that Sekiguchi guy, right.*