# Use of 悪ィ over 悪い

Tags: colloquial-language, katakana, contractions

> それが良{い}いのか悪{わり}ィのか正{ただ}しいことなのか、少し考{かんが}える。

I interpret this clause from 僕のヒーローアカデミア as "As to whether that is a good thing or a bad thing or something correct, I will think about it a little."

Why is 悪{わり}ィ used instead of 悪{わる}い (i.e. why the り syllable after わ rather than the る syllable)? Also, why is the い at the end written in 小さいカタカナ rather than ひらがな?

Comment: Related (See @Earthliŋ's answer): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/9831 ... and maybe: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40081/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in @Earthliŋ's answer that I linked above, this kind of sound change occurs quite often in colloquial speech.

> /ui/ → /ii/
>   あつい → あちい・あちぃ・あちー
>   わるい → わりい・わりぃ・わりー
>   だるい → だりい・だりぃ・だりー

This is informal, and usually sounds masculine.

> why is the い at the end written in 小さいカタカナ rather than ひらがな?

Katakana often look slangy, so I think they wanted to make it look more slangy.

Edit: As commented by @Sjiveru, the Kanatana ィ is also working as a cue for the slang pronunciation; 悪ィ with no furigana would still probably be read as わりい.

Comment: I'd see the katakana as an extra cue for the slang pronunciation. If I saw 悪ィ with no furigana, I'd still probably read it as わりい.

Comment: @Sjiveru Good point, thanks for pointing it out.