# What does 微温い mean in this context?

Tags: words, parsing, word-usage

I read a line in a book where the speaker is berating another party.

> 悪く言われてるのは、誰のせいだと思ってやがる。お前が微温いこと言ってるからだろうが

I can't figure out the appropriate way to parse this without understanding the correct usage of 微温い.

Is the speaker saying the other guy talks about stupid things perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I see that [Weblio has an entry for this spelling](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%AE%E6%B8%A9%E3%81%84).  They suggest that this is an alternative spelling for ぬくい or ぬるい.  Sense 3 is given as *"slow; stupid"*, which would seem to fit your context.

Comment: ぬるい usually means "lax", "lenient" or "lacking dignity" rather than "stupid".

Comment: @naruto the furigana says "ぬり" so it's read as "ぬりい" if that makes a difference? Going by your comment, do I drop the "言ってる" in translation? I'm not sure how 言ってる would play into the "lenient" meaning.

Comment: @Hinolu Oh, then the word is definitely ぬるい. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51863/5010 This ぬるい is an antonym of 厳しい or 厳格な.

Comment: @Hinolu, as Naruto clarifies, the "stupid" sense is more for the ぬくい reading.  For ぬるい, "lax" or "lenient" don't really fit too well as English translations in this context, but related senses "unreliable, undependable" might work better.