# "Workin Hard" -Fuji Kaze Song lyric the verb "かったり" -

Tags: verbs, dialects

I really cant understand which verb is かったり" here 結果なんぞかったりーわ

Any guesses ? Is it a dialect ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40081/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51862/9831 /ui/ ⇒ /ii/ Eg. わるい⇒わりい、あつい⇒あちい、かったるい⇒かったりい

Comment: The original adjective is [かったるい](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B%E3%81%84).