# What does オト mean here?

Tags: translation, slang

I ran along this sentence while reading a novel online. To put it into context, 3 guys were drinking beer at home to celebrate something. Guy 1 had his arm around Guy 2's neck in a friendly way. Guy 2 then said this.

早く外さねーとオトされっぞ

I'm slightly beyond a beginner in terms of a japanese but the only part I understand here is the 早く. As far as I know, 外さねー has mupltiple meanings and the biggest problem is I don't know what オト here is supposed to be.

If this info helps at all, Guy 2 was in his 20s while Guy 1 was in his 30s

Comment: Guy 3 said this sentence, didn't he?

Comment: @YuuichiTam 僕も一瞬そう思ったのですが、締められている本人が焦ってこう言っている可能性もゼロではないのかなーと。（friendly wayと言っているのとは矛盾しますが）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verb is often written in katakana when a slangy/tricky meaning is intended (e.g., ヤる = "to kill, to f**k", シメる = "to torture", イく = "to trip (with drug)"). This オト is part of the verb 落とす. See the seventh definition of [落とす on jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%20%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%20):

> 7. to make someone swoon (judo) <sub>​Martial arts term</sub>

外さ[ねー](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010)と is 外さないと, and 外す here means "to release/unlock".

> 早く外さねーとオトされっぞ。
>   = 早く外さないと落とされるぞ。
>   If [I/you] don't get rid soon, [I/you] will be made unconscious.