# What's the meaning of ぜってーつえー

Tags: meaning

I've found this expression on a manga and I don't know if the correct translation be Absolutely strong 絶対強い

Comment: Depending on the context ‘definitely’ might be more appropriate than ‘absolutely’, but you basically have it right!

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/9831 (I'm not sure if you're asking about the pronunciation change of たい→てー, よい→えー or the meaning of 絶対強い)