# What is the meaning of 上げて落としたみてー?

Tags: meaning, verbs, syntax

I'm reading this manga, and came accross the following monologue:

> たかが弦ごときで世界の終わりみてーなツラしやがって
>
> 俺が上げて落としたみてーで後味ワリーだろがッ
>
> 俺の昼寝返せ!!!

I can't understand what 上げて落としたみて means. Is this an expression? Are those verbs all changing each others meanings?

I've found those translations so far: "I'd feel bad if I were to leave now", "you make me feel bad just looking at you, and gives me a bad feeling"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

みてー is a contracted form of みたい ("is like ～"). It's an instance of [/ai/-to-/ee/ contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010). 上げて is the te-form of 上げる, and 落とす is a verb. Therefore a very literal translation is "It's like I raised it and then dropped it".

上げて落とす is a slangy expression which may be called an idiom. It roughly means "to set someone's expectations and then disappoint them", "to praise something and then disparage", etc. 上げる basically means "to elevate", but it also has slangy meanings like "to praise", "to flatter" or "to hype". 落とす is to "to drop", but it also means "to say negative things about something", "to disappoint", etc.