# How should I understand 「よくね」in this comic?

Tags: interpretation

In the final comic of the web series 百日後に死ぬワニ ("The Crocodile Who Dies After 100 Days"), which you can access [here if you don't mind the spoiler](https://twitter.com/yuukikikuchi/status/1240946299467259905), the crocodile receives this final message:

> [image: The message]

How should I understand「よくね」? How would the meaning differ if it was 「いいね」 instead (the translation I would expect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> よくね？ = よくない？ = "Isn't it nice?"

As for this particular word form, it is a relatively recent slang in casual speech. This ね was developed from ～ない？ which functions as tag question "isn't it?", thus always carries a mild to acute uptalk intonation, whether or not written with a question mark.

Its grammatical construction follows the etymology. That is, `[noun/na-adj] + じゃね？`, `[i-adj] + くね？`, and `[verb]-未然(nai-stem) + ね？` (in which case means "why don't —?").

The most remarkable feature of this expression which is not predictable from its origin is the completely flattened phrasal accent.

> いいんじゃね{LHHHHH}？ vs いいんじゃない{HLLLLLL}？
>   やばくね{LHHH}？ vs やばくない{LHLLL}？
>   かえらね{LHHH}？ vs かえらない{LHHLL}？
>   (the effect of question intonation is excluded; all examples have a rise in the last syllable)

This effectively yields a straightly upward phonetic realization, very much close to that of an English yes-no question sentence.

Comment: Fascinating that it has an unusual pitch accent.

Answer (score 1):

This よくね is not よく + sentence ending particle ね, but よく + ない, with the dialectal pronunciation ねえ shortened to ね.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've not seen this kind of shortening before, what dialect group is it characteristic of?

Comment: @jogloran This is another example of [/ai/-to-/ee/ contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010).

Comment: It's the shortening which I was more interested in.