# What does the phrase 「けぇっちまえ」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

I came across the expression from the following dialogue.

After a boy told an old man with this sentence.

> しっかりしねえか おっちゃん！　いったい なにがあったんだ きょう！

The old man punched him at the face and said this sentence.

> やかましい　つべこべぬかすな　てめえなんざ　**けぇっちまえ**ーっ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

けぇっちまえーっ means 帰{かえ}っちまえ. けえる is a working-class accent of かえる in Tokyo. It is 東京下町ことば. A sound of "ai" changes to that of "ee" in that accent in some words such as ちげーねー(違いない), でぇーこん(だいこん). [http://www.muse.dti.ne.jp/~squat/tokyoben.htm](http://www.muse.dti.ne.jp/%7Esquat/tokyoben.htm)

「～ ちまえ」is a rough way of saying 「～ てしまえ」. So けぇっちまえーっ is something like "Just get out!".

Comment: 正確には"ai"→"ee"になるんじゃないかと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。訂正します。

Comment: These sound changes are also mentioned in [my answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/1628) to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/1628).

Comment: 「～ **ち**まえ」のところが「～ **てし**まえ」ということは、言わなくていいんでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。付け加えた方が親切ですね。