# Usage of ちまう (not "sense of regret" or "accidently do" usage)

Tags: word-usage

I am familiar with the different variations of ちまう, じまう, しまう, ちゃう etc.

I am mostly familiar with the "sense of regret" or "accidently do" usage, but I am confused in sentences like this:

> どうでもいい潰しちまえ！
>
> 化け物を殺せ 殺せ 殺しちまえ!
>
> 行っちまえ!

Comment: Does this help? [Vて+しまう？ 他の使い方がある？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36672/43676)

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84527/what-does-the-phrase-%e3%81%91%e3%81%87%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1%e3%81%be%e3%81%88-mean