# What's the meaning of じゃねーよ and じゃねえん?

Tags: meaning, contractions

I'm actually getting a little confused about these words' meaning,

The original sentence is:

> 生まれちゃった☆ じゃねーよ! ハムスターじゃねえんだぞ!

Does じゃねーよ mean "Not....., you know?" Something like that?

Is it a colloquial form of じゃない?

Is じゃねえん also a colloquial form? Does it mean too bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ねー and ねえ are both corrupted ない ([ai-to-ee contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010)). よ and ぞ are sentence-final particles (ぞ sounds relatively stronger). んだ is short of のだ, where this の is an explanatory-*no*, which in this case is used to convince the listener.

- じゃねーよ = じゃないよ = ではない + よ
- じゃねえんだぞ = じゃないんだぞ = ではない + の + だ + ぞ

Thus a very literal translation would be:

> Not "[happened to be] born!" [It] is not a hamster!

The first Xじゃねーよ is a common pattern of *tsukkomi* used after repeating someone's silly statement. It's like "How dare you say X?", "X? Seriously?" or simply "Ha! X!".

Comment: Is the meaning of this sentence clear without context? Is it weird to use 生まれる with humans rather than animals for example. I didn't think so but I can't imagine what else this could imply.

Comment: @user3856370 This `☆` strongly smells like [tehepero](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/12/tehepero.html), so someone is *pretending* this 生まれちゃった is a small mistake. That is, this 生まれちゃった actually refers to something serious.